# Binary Search Trees: Height of a node in an AVL tree

Tags: java, data-structures, nodes, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Here is my AVL tree that I had to make (hopefully large enough to see clearly)

http://oi46.tinypic.com/2426fer.jpg

I know my tree is correct for what I had to do, but I am unsure about the height of the AVL tree and how that works, as you can probably see within my drawing. Really hope you can help, I understand the concept of everything else that has to do with AVL trees. Thanks

---

Comment: Does [the Wikipedia article on AVL trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) help?

Comment: The drawing seems correct to me. Note that I'd appreciate computer-generated images.

Comment: Your question is how to track the balance efficiently? [This is explained in the article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Insertion) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted a previous question in which you were having a problem with your binarySearchTree. Here was the solution I wrote before you deleted the question. Maybe it'll help.

```
            if (tree.left == null && tree.right == null) {
                    if (compResult < 0) {
                            tree.left.data = item;
                            return true;
                    }
                    if (compResult > 0) {
                            tree.right.data = item;
                            return true;
                    }
            }
            if (compResult < 0) {
                    if (tree.left == null) {        //RED FLAG 
                            tree.left.data = item;  //BUT tree.left IS NULL!!
                            return true;
                    } else
                            add(tree = tree.left, item, count);
            }
            if (compResult > 0) {
                    if (tree.right == null) {       //RED FLAG
                            tree.right.data = item; //BUT tree.right IS NULL!!
                            return true;
                    } else
                            add(tree = tree.right, item, count);
            }
```

To fix these, create a new node and then assign it to tree.left or tree.right.

You should do an iterative add rather than a recursive one, it's faster.